# How to upload a pdf file when details are sent as body data

Tags: jmeter

I am developing JMeter script for an application in which I need to upload file. Let me mention the steps below:

1. As the application relies on Windows based authentication so I could not use JMeter for recording the steps. Instead I used Blazemeter Chrome extension.
2. On using the Blazemeter Chrome extension I observed that the details including the uploaded file were recorded in the Parameters section.
3. I checked the Use multipart/form-data checkbox and then ran the test. But it failed.
4. Then I used the network tab of chrome to capture the network traffic. Issue with this is that the details sent including the uploaded file were not even displayed in the Parameters section of network tab.
5. Then I deleted all details from the Parameters section and then entered details in the File Upload tab (note that multipart/form-data checkbox was selected). I ran the test again but it failed.
6. Then I downloaded Fiddler everywhere to capture network traffic. In this case the details were recorded in the Body -> Form-Data section. Here the issue is for the keys which correspond to file upload the value has weird values which I am not able to comprehend. Something similar to "%PDF-1.3......" and so on. What is this supposed to contain, the file path ?
7. Now I want to know where should I have the details in JMeter ? In the Parameters section or Body Data section or the File Upload section ? And should I select the checkbox corresponding to Use multipart/form-data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> As the application relies on Windows based authentication so I could not use JMeter for recording the steps

You could add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and supply your credentials, domain and so on there, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) for more details.

Make sure to copy the file you're uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder

If you need to pass the file in the body data put relative or full path to the file you're uploading in the "Files Upload" tab and make sure that "Use multipart/form-data" is NOT checked.